# How do I obtain a percentage accuracy for an LSTM

Tags: lstm, accuracy, metric

I've got an LSTM trained for time series forecasting and I've seen people online report their LSTMs accuracy in %s such as 85% accurate etc, how do I obtain a metric like this? so far I was just using MAE

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE). There are various different formulations, which differ in whether the actuals or the predictions are used in the denominator, and what one takes averages over.

You may be interested in [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352)

Comment: I did take a look at the MAPE, however ive got MinMax scaled data and its stock prediction (ik they can't be predicted im just trying to learn RNNs) so I assume I cant use MAPE right? although that was an educational read , thanks, I'll take a look at the weighted MAPE you mentioned

Comment: @pythonnewbie There are issues with MAPE, discussed in the link. However, it should be possible to at least calculate the value. What do you think keeps you from doing so?